# How i can determine if an abstract method is implemented?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I'm using a very large delphi third party library without source code, this library has several classes with abstract methods. I need to determine when an abtract method is implemented by a Descendant class in runtime to avoid the `EAbstractError: Abstract Error` and shows a custom message to the user or use another class instead.

for example in this code I want to check in runtime if the `MyAbstractMethod` is implemented.

```
type
  TMyBaseClass = class
  public
    procedure MyAbstractMethod; virtual; abstract;
  end;

  TDescendantBase = class(TMyBaseClass)
  public
  end;

  TChild = class(TDescendantBase)
  public
    procedure MyAbstractMethod; override;
  end;

  TChild2 = class(TDescendantBase)
  end;
```

How I can determine if an abstract method is implemented in a Descendant class in runtime?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can use the Rtti, the [`GetDeclaredMethods`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/RTTI.TRttiType.GetDeclaredMethods) function get a list of all the methods that are declared in the reflected (current) type. So you can check if the method is present in the list returned by this function.

```
function MethodIsImplemented(const AClass:TClass;MethodName : string): Boolean;
var
  m   : TRttiMethod;
begin
  Result := False;
  for m in TRttiContext.Create.GetType(AClass.ClassInfo).GetDeclaredMethods do
  begin
   Result := CompareText(m.Name, MethodName)=0;
   if Result then
    break;
  end;
end;
```

or you can compare the [`Parent.Name`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/RTTI.TRttiObject.Parent) property of the [TRttiMethod](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/RTTI.TRttiMethod) and check if match with the current class name.

```
function MethodIsImplemented(const AClass:TClass;MethodName : string): Boolean;
var
  m   : TRttiMethod;
begin
  Result := False;
  m:=TRttiContext.Create.GetType(AClass.ClassInfo).GetMethod(MethodName);
  if m<>nil then
   Result:=CompareText(AClass.ClassName,m.Parent.Name)=0; 
end;
```

Answer (score 5):

Look at the implementation of the 32-bit version of the `TStream.Seek()` method in the VCL source code (in `Classes.pas`). It performs a check to make sure the 64-bit version of `Seek()` has been overridden before calling it.  It doesn't involve `TRttiContext` lookups to do that, just a simple loop through its Parent/Child VTable entries, similar to how Zoë's answer shows.

Answer (score 5):

```
function ImplementsAbstractMethod(AObj: TMyBaseClass): Boolean;
type
  TAbstractMethod = procedure of object;
var
  BaseClass: TClass;
  BaseImpl, Impl: TAbstractMethod;
begin
  BaseClass := TMyBaseClass;
  BaseImpl := TMyBaseClass(@BaseClass).MyAbstractMethod;
  Impl := AObj.MyAbstractMethod;
  Result := TMethod(Impl).Code <> TMethod(BaseImpl).Code;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, but if use this way I need to implement a function for each class type and I prefear a more general solution.

Comment: I am not sure if your code is correct. `ImplementsAbstractMethod(TChild2.Create)` will return true, but neither `TChild2`, nor `TDescendantBase` have overridden the abstract `MyAbstractMethod` of `TMyBaseClass`. http://pastebin.com/JufNPJkg

Comment: @rinntech: Thanks for the heads up. I've updated the answer with correct code.