# Delphi OOP force to re-implement method from inherited class

Tags: delphi

I have a child class `TChildClass` that descend from `TBaseClass`. `TBaseClass` has a method `function foo: string;` that `TChildClass` must always implement!

```
IMyInterface = Interface(IInterface)
    function foo: string;
end;

TBaseClass = class(TInterfacedObject, IMyInterface)
  public
    function foo: string;
end;

TChildClass = class(TBaseClass , IMyInterface)
  public
    function foo: string;
end;
```

i want `TChildClass` always implement `function foo` and call inherited from `TBaseClass`:

```
function TBaseClass.foo: string
begin
    Result := 'Hello';
end;

function TChildClass.foo: string
begin
    Result := inherited;

    Result := Result + ' world!';
end;
```

how to make it?

Comment: You can't get the compiler to check for every single programming mistake. If you could then you wouldn't need programmers. This kind of requirement should be enforced by your tests. You do have tests right?

Comment: You could make `foo` abstract (i.e. `virtual; abstract;`). That way you should get a warning if you don't implement (`override;`) it in a descendant and instantiate a variable of that descendant. But then, foo cannot have an implementation in the base class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot **force** the compiler to require the override at compile-time.

In order for `TChildClass` to override `foo()`, `foo()` needs to be declared as `virtual` in `TBaseClass` (but NOT also `abstract`, since you want `TBaseClass.foo()` to have a default implementation, otherwise the compiler will complain!).  And, unlike with C++, Delphi does not *require* abstract methods to be overridden, and it allows code to create instances of abstract classes at runtime (even though *calling* abstract methods that have not been overridden will cause runtime errors).

However, you can **validate** at runtime whether `TBaseClass.foo()` has been overridden in a descendant or not, eg:

```
type
  IMyInterface = Interface(IInterface)
    function foo: string;
  end;

  TBaseClass = class(TInterfacedObject, IMyInterface)
  public
    function foo: string; virtual;
  end;

  TChildClass = class(TBaseClass, IMyInterface)
  public
    function foo: string; override;
  end;

function TBaseClass.foo: string;
type
  TFoo = function: string of object;
var
  Impl, Base: TFoo;
  ClassTBase: TClass;
begin
  Impl := foo;
  ClassTBase := TBaseClass;
  Base := TBaseClass(@ClassTBase).foo;
  if TMethod(Impl).Code = TMethod(Base).Code then
    raise Exception.CreateFmt('foo() not implemented in class ''%s''', [ClassName]);
  Result := 'Hello';
end;

function TChildClass.foo: string;
begin
  Result := inherited foo;
  Result := Result + ' world!';
end;
```

But, there is nothing you can do to **force** `TChildClass.foo()` to call `inherited`, that is strictly up to `TChildClass` to decide on its own.

Comment: Interesting, and probably way more efficient than mine.

Comment: @GolezTrol which is funny, because this same technique is mentioned in a [different answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8314123/65863) to the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305008/) you linked to in your answer here.  I guess you did not read them all before posting.

Comment: True. I already thought about solving it through the RTTI, and found that question while filling in the details of the example I posted. Apparently the XY-problem applies to answering too. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can't per se. However you can achieve what you want a slightly different way.

```
type
IMyInterface = Interface(IInterface)
    function foo: string;
end;

TBaseClass = class(TInterfacedObject, IMyInterface)
  protected
    function fooForced : string; virtual; abstract;
  public
    function foo: string;
end;

TChildClass = class(TBaseClass , IMyInterface)
  protected
    function fooForced: string; override;
end;

function TBaseClass.foo: string;
begin
    Result := 'Hello' + FooForced;
end;

function TChildClass.fooForced: string;
begin
    Result := ' world!';
end;
```

Note - you must take heed of 'creating abstract class' warnings!

Comment: @RemyLebeau fooForced is abstract, not foo. I have checked and the above compiles.

Comment: you are right, I didnt notice that a second method was being used. However, as previously mentioned, just because it is `abstract` doesnt **force** the compiler to **require** an `override`, it will happily allow `fooForced` to remain `abstract` and will let the user instantiate `TBaseClass` and call `fooForced` without an implementation behind it

Comment: @RemyLebeau, yes I know. Hence my comment about not ignoring creating abstract class warning. At the end of the day you can lead a horse to water but you can't make it drink as is shown in the original OP post where inherited is called, but the result ignored!

Answer (score 2):

I think using an `abstract` method one way or another is probably the cleanest way to go. Like Dsm already mentioned, you can't get it *exactly* as you want, because an abstract method doesn't have an implementation, so you can't call that method in the baseclass.

This alternative is pretty close, but it requires digging into the RTTI. It's up to you if it's worth it for your purpose. What is basically does: dig into the list of methods of the class. For the method with the given name, check what the classname of its implementor is. If it is TBaseClass, throw an exception, otherwise continue.

I'm pretty sure that his will fail if you would implement an overload of the method `foo`, though, so it's not waterproof. Maybe there are ways to check if the found method is indeed an override, but TRttiMethod doesn't seem to provide anything for that out of the box.

The code example is heavily inspired on [RRUZ's answer, here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8305032/511529).

```
TBaseClass = class(TInterfacedObject, IMyInterface)
  private
    procedure ValidateDescendantImplements(MethodName: string);
  public
    function foo: string;
end;

function TBaseClass.foo: string;
begin
    ValidateDescendantImplements('foo');

    Result := 'Hello';
end;

procedure TBaseClass.ValidateDescendantImplements(MethodName: string);
var
  m: TRttiMethod;
begin
  for m in TRttiContext.Create.GetType(Self.ClassType).GetDeclaredMethods do
  begin
   if SameText(m.Name, MethodName) then
     if m.Parent.Name <> TBaseClass.ClassName then
       Exit
  end;
  raise Exception.CreateFmt('%s needs to be overridden', [MethodName]);
end;
```

Usage:

```
TChildClass.Create.foo; // Works
TBaseClass.Create.foo; // Throws exception
```

Comment: You don't need to resort to the overhead of `TRttiContext` to implement the validation. Look at the implementation of the 32bit version of `TStream.Seek()` in `System.Classes.pas`, it performs a similar validation to make sure that the 64bit version of `Seek()` has been overridden in a descendant class before calling it, using only the stream's `ClassType` and `ClassParent` properties to perform the validation. See my answer, I have adapted that technique to this situation.